# Error compiling mupdf library android

Tags: android, android-ndk, mupdf

I am compiling mupdf 1.2 from [here](http://code.google.com/p/mupdf/downloads/detail?name=mupdf-1.2-source.zip&can=2&q=) it does not have any sub directory `generated` but when I try to compile uding

```
 $ndk-build
```

in cygwin this error occurs

```
 jni/../../pdf/pdf_cmap_table.c:5:35: fatal error: ../generated/cmap_cns.h: 
 No such file or directory compilation terminated.
 /cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r8e/build/core/build-binary.mk:269: recipe for target 
 `obj/local/armeabi/objs/mupdfcore/__/__/pdf/pdf_cmap_table.o' failed
 make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/mupdfcore/__/__/pdf/pdf_cmap_table.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Have you find the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by first compiling the third-party libraries using visual studio...

just follow steps on this [link](http://mupdf.blogspot.in/)

Comment: Please add details about how you solved the problem instead of just a link.